# Constant pressure, constant wall thickness, expanding volume = explosion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science

Just been idly thinking about a gas cylinder I sometimes use. Pressure is about 200 Bar, or roughly 20 MPa. If I kept the same thickness of steel wall, and the same pressure, but made cylinders bigger and bigger would it at some point rupture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can provide a reasoned and approximate answer by using [Barlow's formula for pipes](http://www.engineersedge.com/calculators/pipe_bust_calc.htm).

If we consider the cylinder as a short pipe then the bursting pressure is given by:

$$\large{P =\frac{2ST}{(OD)(SF)}}.$$

With $P$ pipe pressure, $S$ tensile strength of the cylinder material, $T$ material thickness, $(OD)$ outer diameter of the cylinder and $(SF)$ an engineering safety factor.

If we set $(SF)=1$ then $P$ is the *bursting pressure* in function of the other variables.

As we can see, the bursting pressure is inversely proportional to the outer diameter (size) of the cylinder:

$$P \propto \frac{1}{(OD)}.$$

So you are entirely correct in stating that, *all other things being equal*, bigger cylinders would at some critical $(OD)$ *rupture*.